# How do I write an If statement in my stored procedure based on what value is passed through a specific variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I need to modify. There are 4 possible values that can be passed through the variable @Company. The SQL looks like this....

```
-- Create #House table
CREATE  TABLE #Houses  
(
    iHouse_ID       int,
    cName           varchar(50),
    cNumber         varchar(10),
    cPhoneNumber1   varchar(25),
    cAddressLine1   varchar(50),
    cCity           varchar(30),
    cStateCode      varchar(2),
    cZipCode        varchar(10),
    iUnitsAvailable int,
    iRegOpsNumber   int,
    cOpsName        varchar(50),
    iRegionID       int,
    cRegionName     varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Houses (iHouse_ID, cName, cNumber, cPhoneNumber1, cAddressLine1, cCity, CStateCode, cZipCode, iUnitsAvailable, iRegOpsNumber, cOpsName, iRegionID, cRegionName)
    SELECT
        h2.iHouse_ID, h.cName, h.cNumber, h.cPhoneNumber1,
        h.cAddressLine1, h.cCity, h.CStateCode, h.cZipCode, 
        h.iUnitsAvailable, r.RegOpsNumber, r.opsname, 
        r.iRegion_ID, r.regionname
    FROM
        rw.fn_GetScopeHouses (@Scope, @dtReport, NULL, NULL, 0) h2  
    JOIN    
        House h ON h.iHouse_ID = h2.iHouse_ID
                AND h.cCompanyID = @CompanyID
    JOIN    
        rw.vw_Reg_Ops r on r.opsareaID = h.iOpsArea_ID
```

Now, the modification that I have to make is if the variable passed in @CompanyID is '0000' then I need to add an AND h2.ihouse_ID not in..so that the SQL becomes...

```
FROM
    rw.fn_GetScopeHouses (@Scope, @dtReport, NULL, NULL, 0) h2  
JOIN    
    House h ON h.iHouse_ID = h2.iHouse_ID
            AND h.cCompanyID = '0000'
JOIN    
    rw.vw_Reg_Ops r ON r.opsareaID = h.iOpsArea_ID
                    AND h2.ihouse_ID NOT IN (SELECT h2.iHouse_ID 
                                             FROM rw.fn_GetScopeHouses (0, getdate(), NULL, NULL, 0) h2 
JOIN    
    House h ON h.iHouse_ID = h2.iHouse_ID
JOIN    
    rw.vw_Reg_Ops r ON r.opsareaID = h.iOpsArea_ID
JOIN 
    DBPROD02.houses_App.dbo.subAcct ON right(h.cGLSubaccount, 3) = RIGHT(RTRIM(consolsub), 3) 
WHERE 
    S4future02 = 'FHLMC')
```

I tried...

```
from    rw.fn_GetScopeHouses (@Scope, @dtReport, NULL, NULL, 0) h2  
JOIN    House h on  h.iHouse_ID = h2.iHouse_ID
AND h.cCompanyID = @CompanyID
JOIN    rw.vw_Reg_Ops r on r.opsareaID = h.iOpsArea_ID
IF(@CompanyID = '0000')
 BEGIN
    AND h2.ihouse_ID not in (select h2.iHouse_ID 
    from    rw.fn_GetScopeHouses (0, getdate(), NULL, NULL, 0) h2   
    JOIN    House h on  h.iHouse_ID = h2.iHouse_ID
    JOIN    rw.vw_Reg_Ops r on r.opsareaID = h.iOpsArea_ID
    JOIN DBPROD02.houses_App.dbo.subAcct on right(h.cGLSubaccount,3)=RIGHT(RTRIM(consolsub), 3) 
    where S4future02 = 'FHLMC')
END
```

but when I tried to save the change, I got the error

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 186
Must declare the scalar variable "@CompanyID".
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 194
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
```

The variable has been declared here...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [rw].[sp_EFT_NoticeXLSNoDraw]
    (@Scope varchar(50), @AcctPeriod char(6), @CompanyID nchar(10)) 
AS
```

I am at a loss on how to proceed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you can compare @CompanyID type nchar(10) with whatever the type of h.cCompanyID?

Comment: Yes. The values passed are the values in the cCompanyID column.

Comment: First of all, you did not declare @CompanyID before you put in your query, use `declare @companyID int`, and then what is your full SP code? third, you need to combine the query condition both in 'if` clause, otherwise for static condition, put after `where`, last but not least, the syntax of your query has problems, if you do not mind, paste the entire SP

Comment: How do I past the entire SP, LONG? It wont let me because it is too long.

Comment: @tetteh there are some good solutions below that should suffice, no?

Comment: Wow!! Just refreshed and I am just seeing the answers below! Thanks scsimon. I'll try them and report back on what worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to just check it at the beginning since there is only one fork, or one condition you need to check on. Granted you are duplicating your code but at least it's easier to debug and manage...

```
CREATE someProcedure (@CompanyID varchar(16)) --insert other variables as needed
AS


CREATE  TABLE #Houses (
iHouse_ID       int,
cName           varchar(50),
cNumber         varchar(10),
cPhoneNumber1   varchar(25),
cAddressLine1   varchar(50),
cCity           varchar(30),
cStateCode      varchar(2),
cZipCode        varchar(10),
iUnitsAvailable int,
iRegOpsNumber   int,
cOpsName        varchar(50),
iRegionID       int,
cRegionName     varchar(50))

IF  @CompanyID = '0000'
    BEGIN

        insert  into    #Houses (
        iHouse_ID, 
        cName, 
        cNumber,
        cPhoneNumber1,
        cAddressLine1, 
        cCity, 
        CStateCode, 
        cZipCode,
        iUnitsAvailable, 
        iRegOpsNumber, 
        cOpsName, 
        iRegionID, 
        cRegionName)
        select  
        h2.iHouse_ID,
        h.cName, 
        h.cNumber, 
        h.cPhoneNumber1,
        h.cAddressLine1, 
        h.cCity, 
        h.CStateCode, 
        h.cZipCode, 
        h.iUnitsAvailable, 
        r.RegOpsNumber,
        r.opsname, 
        r.iRegion_ID, 
        r.regionname
        from    rw.fn_GetScopeHouses (@Scope, @dtReport, NULL, NULL, 0) h2  
        JOIN    House h on  h.iHouse_ID = h2.iHouse_ID
        AND h.cCompanyID = '0000'
        JOIN    rw.vw_Reg_Ops r on r.opsareaID = h.iOpsArea_ID
        AND h2.ihouse_ID not in (select h2.iHouse_ID 
        from    rw.fn_GetScopeHouses (0, getdate(), NULL, NULL, 0) h2   
        JOIN    House h on  h.iHouse_ID = h2.iHouse_ID
        JOIN    rw.vw_Reg_Ops r on r.opsareaID = h.iOpsArea_ID
        JOIN DBPROD02.houses_App.dbo.subAcct on right(h.cGLSubaccount,3)=RIGHT(RTRIM(consolsub), 3) 
where S4future02 = 'FHLMC')
    END

ELSE

    BEGIN

        insert  into    #Houses (
        iHouse_ID, 
        cName, 
        cNumber,
        cPhoneNumber1,
        cAddressLine1, 
        cCity, 
        CStateCode, 
        cZipCode,
        iUnitsAvailable, 
        iRegOpsNumber, 
        cOpsName, 
        iRegionID, 
        cRegionName)
        select  
        h2.iHouse_ID,
        h.cName, 
        h.cNumber, 
        h.cPhoneNumber1,
        h.cAddressLine1, 
        h.cCity, 
        h.CStateCode, 
        h.cZipCode, 
        h.iUnitsAvailable, 
        r.RegOpsNumber,
        r.opsname, 
        r.iRegion_ID, 
        r.regionname
        from    rw.fn_GetScopeHouses (@Scope, @dtReport, NULL, NULL, 0) h2  
        JOIN    House h on  h.iHouse_ID = h2.iHouse_ID
        AND h.cCompanyID = @CompanyID
        JOIN    rw.vw_Reg_Ops r on r.opsareaID = h.iOpsArea_ID
    END

   SELECT * FROM #Houses
```

Comment: I did this and it worked!! Thanks scsimon. It is not pretty, but it worked and I needed it to work today!!

Comment: No worries @Tetteh and I like to favor simple and easily maintainable code versus some cryptic complex logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `case` statement in your `join` conditions that defaults to a matching comparison if the value in `@Company` isn't `0000`:

```
select Columns
from Tables t
    join OtherTables ot
        on t.Column1 = ot.Column2
            and case when @Company = '0000'
                     then case when ihouse not in(<values>)
                               then 1
                               else 0
                               end
                     else 1
                     end = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement something like below with two different sql statements in your procedure. The below is a pseudocode.

```
If @CompanyID == '0000' 
--Sql Statement
else
--Sql Statement
endif;
```